# Goal setting for the end of the year

Tags: career-development, performance-reviews

We started using a goal tracking/performance review software earlier this year. I set a goal initially that has not been fulfilled. I know we can change our goals at any point, but I'm wondering if I should.

The goal I made has not been achieved because I didn't receive the right kind of assignment. It's not that I couldn't do it, it that I haven't been given the opportunity.

In general, is it bad to have an unachieved goal? Should I change it to something I know I will achieve in the next two months? I feel like that is cheating me out of being honest with my superior about what kind of work I would prefer to do.

Comment: Others have posted advice about how to handle this now, but you should also thing about what this means. You set a goal, and presumably your superior accepted it (possibly implicitly). Then your boss never assigned you work that could allow you to achieve your goal, nor did they suggest you change your goal.This indicates a breakdown in the communication process that you should probably talk to your boss about. Maybe your boss forgot about/doesn't care enough about your goal or the goal system. Maybe your boss knew your goal couldn't be achieved but didn't want to tell you. Talk to your boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In general, is it bad to have an unachieved goal? Should I change it
>   to something I know I will achieve in the next two months? I feel like
>   that is cheating me out of being honest with my superior about what
>   kind of work I would prefer to do.

Every company I have ever worked for has provided corporate guidelines for setting and modifying annual performance goals. And every company I have ever worked for has different "rules".

You need to coordinate your actions with your manager, with your company guidelines and with the repercussions that may occur based on your actions.

I'll try to answer the specifics in terms of my company's current rules, but remember - your mileage may vary. Talk to your Manager, Talk to your HR. Consult your own company guidelines first.

> In general, is it bad to have an unachieved goal?

At my company this isn't great. The whole point of having goals is to provide motivation for achieving them.

If it's an overall goal, it may not matter much. If it's an MBO goal, it may cost you a portion of your bonus money.

> Should I change it to something I know I will achieve in the next two months?

In my company, you wouldn't have that option. Goals are locked down within the system we use for tracking goals at a certain period. Two months before year end you wouldn't be able to change anything.

> I feel like that is cheating me out of being honest with my superior about what
>   kind of work I would prefer to do.

In my company, goals aren't about what kind of work you would prefer to do. Instead, they are more about the kind of work you are being explicitly incented (financially) to do.

In my company, you would work with your supervisor/manager when creating or modifying any goals, so no cheating could occur.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is bad in most performance systems to have an unachieved goal. You have to understand how most of these systems work.

They don't care what you did  - only if you did what the system says you were going to do. When they start comparing notes (you did know that managers have to compare and people get downgraded if other managers don't agree with the supervisor's assessment, right?) to determine who among the peple marked highest will actually get the high rating, then it will be easier for your manager to get shot down in presenting you as a high acheiver if you have an unachieved goal even one that you were not given the opportunity to perform. So having an unachieved goal can lower your overall rating even if your boss thinks you are doing outstanding work. Because basically they only have the budget for so many outstandings and that counts as a failure to the other managers who are pushing their own people.

At the lower rating levels, it can be the final excuse to get rid of you.

Nothing about the goals has anything to do with the kind of work you would prefer to do. These automated systems are set up solely to provide metrics that be used to downgrade performance. If too many people meet all tehir goals, I guarantee the golas will be significantly more challenging the next year and everyone who met all his goals will still not get get an outstanding apprasisal because there is no maney in the budget for everyone who deserves an Outstanding to get one in 99.9% of all organizations (excluding some very small start-ups).

If you have things you want to do professionally to grow that involve assignments given to you by your boss, then do not ever rely on the goals to get you there. You need to lobby for those assignments on a regular basis through the year. These goals are at best a bureaucratic process designed to give the illusion the company cares about your goals. They are not intended as work assignements. You need to keep track of what is upcoming that you would like to get assigned to and make sure to directly ask for the assignment and if they can't give it to you, then you need to make sure you get the next one.

Comment: The Performance system I had to deal with in the past was really not that simple... Success and Failure weren't binary, they were a scale 1 to 10. 1 being a total failure, 10 being a total success. They also had a difficulty rating to goals, again 1 to 10. The idea being success in the most trivial of goals is almost in par with failure of the most difficult of goals. (Though to be fair, while that system was "better than most" it was still pretty bad)

Comment: @RualStorge, I have never seen a good performance appraisal system. They are getting worse too as metrics takes over and we get evealuated on what is measurable whether it is what is important or not.

Comment: Agreed, just making the point some are way worse than others.

Comment: I have also never seen one that weighted the goals or tasks either. I have seen people get down rated for not completing one minor task when they did a bunch of important ones that made the company a lot of money. If you have to ability still remove a goal you know you won't complete, by all means do it. There is no downside to doing to and no upside to keeping it.